# JQuery function in different file using Webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I have the following JS in index.js file:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;

$(function () {
  $.fn.mapit = function () { 
    // Do something
  }
}
```

I tried to move the function mapit to another file:

**index.js**

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
window.jQuery = $;
import 'mapit.js'
```

**mapit.js**

```
$(function () {
  $.fn.mapit = function () { 
    // Do something
  }
}
```

But I get an error saying `$ is undefined` in mapit file.

I am building with webpack and the entry point is index.js

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse your imports. `mapit.js` is not importing jquery nor does it define it. index.js does.

Perhaps your best course of action is to move jquery to it's own file (jquery.js), import jquery.js into mapit.js, and import mapit.js into index.js

Comment: I also have JQuery in index.js I just didn't post that information because I thought it was not relevant.

Comment: The problem is not missing jQuery on index.js, but that it is missing from `mapit.js`. So you either import jQuery directly in `mapit.js` or import a module that export `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

Do an `import * as $ from 'jquery';` inside `mapit.js` too.

That's how modules work in JS, you need to import necessary ones in the file you want to use them in. Its not like traditional `<script>` tags